# Need help to understand a peice of while loop code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python online on YouTube. And I have came across a piece of code that is confusing me. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out. Here is the code:

```
command = ""
started = False

while True:
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "start":
        if started:
            print("car already started")
        else:
            started = True
            print("car started")
```

What I didn't understand is how does Python execute double `if`s? And how does it know it is already executed once and if typed start again it would give me another message. Any help would highly appreciated.

Comment: As not mentioned by user glhr and KYDronePilot the else loop changes the variable `started = False` into `started = True` if the command **start** is given. If not it iters (while-loop) until command **start** is given. The method is hazardously written because only the command **start** is required to start the car. This should always be at least a two step verification because you work with machines that may be able to harm you in real-life if not paying attention. (e.g. clutch is in neutral and/or break-peddle is pushed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if`s are nested. The second `if` and `else` are only checked if the first condition is true. This is apparent, since they are indented after the first `if`.

The first `if` checks if the command is to start. If it is, then it checks if the car has already been started. If it has, there is no need to start it again. If not, then it starts the car.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to "transcribe" the code in English:

1. car has not started, no command received yet
2. start an infinite loop (meaning that the steps below will repeat forever, until you terminate/exit the program)
3. take a command from the user, turn it into lowercase, and store it
4. check the command entered by the user. If the command is "start", then check whether the car has started, and start it if it hasn't been already, then go back to step 3. If the user input is not "start", then don't check anything and return directly to step 3.

Comment: wow thank you for very detailed answer. You really make coding look very very easy :). wish u a wonderful day/ night :)